# Question on the relation between the $n$-coskeleton functor and the internal hom-adjunction

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

(First, let me apologize that I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441432/a-question-on-the-relation-of-truncation-tau-leq-n-to-the-internal-hom-adj) an unanswered and related question in the stable case.)

The category $\operatorname{sSet_+}$ of pointed simplicial sets is symmetric monoidal closed, i.e. there is an internal hom $\operatorname{Hom}(B,C)\in \operatorname{sSet_+}$ for any two pointed simplicial sets $B$ and $C$. The internal hom is adjoint to the smash product, i.e.
$$
\operatorname{hom}_{\operatorname{sSet_+}}(A\wedge B, C) \cong \operatorname{hom}_{\operatorname{sSet_+}}(A, \operatorname{Hom}(B,C))
$$
naturally. Let $n$ be a positive integer. To avoid special cases, say $n\geq 5$.

There is a [coskeleton functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+skeleton#Truncation) $\operatorname{cosk}_n(A)$ inducing an isomorphism on all simplicial homotopy groups in degree $<n$.

> Let $A, B$ and $C$ be pointed simplicial sets and suppose that **every** morphism
>   $$
> A\to \operatorname{Hom}(B,C)
> $$
>   is zero up to homotopy (i.e. null-homotopic) after applying $\operatorname{cosk}_n$. Does it follow that every (adjoint) morphism
>   $$
> A\wedge B\to C
> $$
>   is zero up to homotopy after applying $\operatorname{cosk}_n$?

Thank you.